# No internet access while Openvpn is on

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I've recently started a homelab projet and build a server. The server in itself is a VMware hypervisor with two ubuntu server 22.04 running on it (one for file sharing and one to act as a vpn server).

To access this server from outside my home network I've set up an openvpn server.

As client I use laptop with dual boot win10 and ubuntu 20.04 on it.

On win10 I can establish a vpn connection from a remote network (phone network sharing) maintain internet access (standard browsing) and access my home network :

- The ESXI control panel on 192.168.1.17
- The ISP router control panel on 192.168.1.1
- The ubuntu file server on 192.168.1.30 (although I now I need to provide some sort of credentials to access the shared folder but I don't know what those credentials are or which service is asking for them).

However the main issue is on the ubuntu client. I can establish a vpn connection. Client and server logs are ok but I lose all internet connectivity. I can't ping anything except my base IP (192.168.xx.xx) and the NATed IP given by openvpn (10.8.0.2). I can't access my home network either.

At first I thought this could be caused by some server issues however the vpn works great on windows. The ip forwarding and routing seems to work.

I've already seen many answers on this website on server-side troubleshooting but none had any impact on my situation.

I looked for some client side issues but didn't find anything that worked for me.

If you have any idea about the potential origin of this issue (or some tests I can run to find the cause) or if you need specific information let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` line in your `server.conf`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! and yes I do have this line in my server.conf. The issue might just come from a broken install of ubuntu. I've tested today my vpn on a fresh ubuntu 22.04 install and I managed to get a working conection.

Comment: However the new VM is on the same machine as the vpn so I can't get a proper "remote connection" on it. I'll do some further testing.